# DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am getting this error on my code, and I don't know how to fix it ?

```
DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

My code so far:

```
router.post('/users/*', (req, res) => {
  User.create(new User({
    email: req.body.identity.user_email,
    authUserId: req.body.identity.user_id
  }))
  res.json(console.log("User Created"))
})
router.get('/users/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  User.findOne({authUserId: req.params.id}, (err, userr) => {
    if(err) {
      return next(err);
    } else if (userr) {
      res.json(userr.email);
    } else {
      res.json(null)
    }
  });
});
```

Can someone help me get rid of this error. 
Thnx in advance! :)

Comment: You must make sure to catch promise rejections or errors.

Comment: You're not handling any errors that `User.create()` might throw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your application's entry point is `app.js`. So, as you are forwarding `error` as `return next(err);`, there should be someone who will catch that and handle.

generally I place handler on `app.js` before listener function-

```
// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {

  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});
```